# What's the difference between spell an the vim-spell plugin?

Tags: vim

there are the spell function in vim and the vim-spell plugin, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'spell' is a builtin, the 'vimspell'-plugin is a 3rd party plugin which uses `aspell`  or `ispell` to achieve it's goal.

according to `:help spell`:

```
 Note: There also is a vimspell plugin.  If you have it you can 
 do ":help vimspell" to find about it.  But you will probably want 
 to get rid of the plugin and use the 'spell' option instead, it works
 better.
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I do :help spell then the vimspell help is open. That's confuse me. Thanx again...

Comment: @zzeroo: in my vim73 'spell.txt' is opened. dunno what happens on your side of the screen :)